# Newbie needs help with processing a 3D scanned tree

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I'm a marine biologist and I'm currently working on a project to 3D print a 1m^3 replica of mangrove trees for the use of ex situ (offsite/in the laboratory) observation of fish behavior.

I've recently posted a question on Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/3DScanning/comments/gebzg2/help_with_scanning_a_tree/) and got an advice to try out Blender to process my 3D scanned trees. I have some questions and was hoping I could get some help getting a better understanding on how this software works.

1. Can I fix holes on my .STL files manually on Sculpt mode (like how I can on images on Photoshop using eraser or brush)? So far I’ve been using the Edit mode, filling with Alt+F, but this mode lags so much on my computer due to the high number of verts, and manual delete is such a pain.
2. I’ve removed some noise using the edit mode, CTRL+L, CTRL+I and delete. However, I can’t figure out how to get rid of linked junk inside the outer layer of my object. Pic: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14cqgzwI-_OGFdGyU2AI2JvygBbWX7GQA
3. When trying to solidify, I get blobs coming out of my scanned object (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BKWV1KmYeLQR5bnJ3lA_h9FLcLLrxlsw) and I don’t know how to fix it. I do have some non manifold edges and intersect faces (checked using the 3D printing toolkit). I saw this post from a few years back but it doesn't seem to work on me. https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/25jxst/easy_way_to_delete_internal_geometry/

Download links to some of the trees I have scanned (.STL):
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Dldxj_EvpznI282SxPEoSUb68BDBY30O
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q9cjOiURe2T1J7dYJRu7ZOapitTdvsNp
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CcBZ1fbjpPw1cu7BHnidkl6xFen3UwQG

Thanks! I'm a newbie so please go easy on me. I definitely have more questions but these should do for now.

Comment: Hi welcome to [blender.se]. Please take the [tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour). Usually only a single question per post is allowed (you create as many threads as you need) but this may be an exception. Please **edit** your post and [upload your images into your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/404048). You have many links in your post, if they go down, the question is hard to understand. Embedding the images will help with that.

Comment: Pretty complicated :-) Like you wrote, I started with selecting the main geometry inverted selection and deleted the unconnected geometry. Any command that would make automatic correction freezes the computer as it is dense and complicated mesh. To help this, you can use decimate modifier, which reduce the number of polygon by percents. I cut the polygons from 2 milions to 600 thousand without loosing too much details, If you don't need much detail you can go lower. I think sculpting wouldn't be helpful with hole closing.